# How do I make a DIV vibrate or buzz? (similar to the iOS move/delete app feature)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I'm working on a website that the user can customize and I'd like to make "vibrate/buzz" an element of the DOM (in my specific case it's a `DIV`). 
I'd like to obtain an effect similar to the one that happens on iOS when you long press any app icon (all the icons get shaky).

Searching on the web I just found this jQuery library:
http://www.dev4web.eu/projects/jquery.vibrate/

But I'm not sure that I'll be able to obtain a nice effect using it.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, where I show how to make [any element shake, rotate, squish, or skew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649470/2430549).  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"jQuery ClassyWiggle allows you to emulate the wiggle effect icons on an iPhone have when you press and hold down on them. "

Check the [Classy Wiggle](https://vox.space/files/jquery/classywiggle/) JQuery plugin by [Marius Stanciu](https://vox.space/?section=5).

Comment: Really good plugin. Does anyone know if Mr. Stanciu participates in SO?

Comment: it can also be done with custom code then why plugin

Comment: Yes, CSS animations are much more accessible now, 3 years later. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could also implement your own animation like this:

```
function shake(){
    $('#div').animate({
        'margin-left': '-=5px',
        'margin-right': '+=5px'
    }, 200, function() {
        $('#div').animate({
            'margin-left': '+=5px',
            'margin-right': '-=5px'
        }, 200, function() {
            //and so on...
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is some Javascript that will do what you're looking for.

```
var times = 10;
var duration = 200;
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    $('div#shake-it').animate({
        left: (i % 2 === 0 ? "-" : "+") + "=50"
    }, duration);
```

Like many of the other solutions, it requires the jQuery library. However it doesn't need any other plugins.

Comment: this is so far the best solution with no dependancies

Answer (score 3):

I built something that was intended to mimic the iOS wiggle effect recently to be used in on top of jQuery sortable. You can see it live on tastemakerx.com where I used it to enhance a collection sorting feature.

Here's the fiddle I started with:
http://jsfiddle.net/jozecuervo/fv8vR/

And here's the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg) translateY(0);}
    15%, 35%, 55%, 75%, 95% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(-2deg) ;}
    25%, 45%, 65%, 85% {-webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(2deg); }
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateY(1px);}    
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-1px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg) translateY(0);}
    15%, 35%, 55%, 75%, 95% {-moz-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(-2deg) ;}
    25%, 45%, 65%, 85% {-moz-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(2deg); }
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateY(1px);}    
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateY(-1px); }  
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
     0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg) translateY(0);}
    15%, 35%, 55%, 75%, 95% {-o-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(-2deg) ;}
    25%, 45%, 65%, 85% {-o-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(2deg); }
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateY(1px);}    
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateY(-1px); }  
}

@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg) translateY(0);}
    15%, 35%, 55%, 75%, 95% {transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(-2deg) ;}
    25%, 45%, 65%, 85% {transform: translateX(1px) rotate(2deg); }
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateY(1px);}    
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateY(-1px); }  
}
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    -moz-animation-name: shake;
    -o-animation-name: shake;
    animation-name: shake;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;    
}
```

Comment: The link seems incorrect and isn't versioned, and I see that your JSFiddle code has changed over time.

Comment: Correct, the fiddle changed because I kept working on the feature I needed. That site sold and the CDN is now down. The css keyframing above still works fine though. Feel free to make a new fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery's plugin:

```
$('#loginL').effect('shake');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a plugin such as `jQuery` Rumble: http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

You could create your own using `animate`.  As an example (To demonstrate how to shake the div):

```
<div id="div">
</div>

<input type="button" id="buzz" />

$("#buzz").click(function() {
   $("#div").animate({
    left: "20px",
   }, 50);

   $("#div").animate({
    left: "-20px",
   }, 50);

   $("#div").animate({
    left: "20px",
   },50);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VRzc9/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$('#shakediv').effect('shake');
```

the shake effect is built in jquery ui , import and use

Answer (score 0):

follow the below example

```
<div class="buzz">
    <!-- Your Div Content Here -->
</div>


<script>

$(docuement).ready(function(){
   buzzMe();
   //or
   buzzMeFor(0)
})
function buzzMe()
{
   $('buzz').css('margin-left','-2');
   delay(500);
   $('buzz').css('margin-left','2');
   delay(500);
   buzzMe()
}

//Or use this function for Specific times
//Call & Pass Arguments 0
function buzzMeFor(count)
{
  count++;
  $('buzz').css('margin-left','-2');
  delay(500);
  $('buzz').css('margin-left','2');
  delay(500);
  if(count!=20)    
    buzzMe(count)    
}
</script>
```

Comment: By Mistakes i pressed enter two times so is published before i completed. Please mark +1 instead of minus.

Answer (score 0):

Using only jQuery's animate function, the following does the trick :

```js
function recursiveShake(jQelement, pixel, counter) {
  if (counter > 0) {
    jQelement.animate({
      'margin-left': '+='.concat(pixel, 'px')}, 
      30, 
      recursiveShake(jQelement, -pixel, counter - 1)
    );
  }
}
// (counter must be even to avoid any shift)
```